# IE 10 (and probably other version) resize necessity

Tags: html, internet-explorer, resize

I'm working on the app in company. Everything works under firefox but in IE 10 I have a problem. I have to resize window to see content of my page after every redirection. Without doing this, I see only blank page:
Here is screen how I see page before resizing:
[image: Without resizing]

And here is correct page content after window resizing:
[image: After resizing]

How to avoid this mannually resizing? Maybe some javascript can realize that? Thanks in advance for help cause this is really annoying problem.

Comment: Can we see some code? what did you try?

Comment: Is the content creation done by JS and triggered by a `resize` event?

Comment: Maybe something wrong with your HTML / CSS? Why does it only work after a resize?

Comment: @Timothy Groote - unfortunately I cannot show code cause it is from company project. I tried to resize window in body onload function but doesn't work. It only resize my page which is in div, not all window (which I expect). How to on load page resize all browser window?

Comment: @Bergi: Yes, one javascript function using 'resize' event. But don't know is that what you mean.

Comment: @putvande: maybe, but don't know what can be wrong. CSS to this project is enormous!

Comment: Show us that function with the `resize` event (you don't need to put the whole project here, so that's fine). Try triggering the event manually.

Comment: This is this function:                     $(window).resize(function() {
    DropBoxMaskPosition(); //my different function
});                                                                 But I'm not sure that this is responsible for that cause I removed all content of my page except sample text in body section (also I removed all javascript imports) and problem is the same.

Comment: Then it's definitely weird. Can you make a minimal demo of that setup which reproduces the issue? [Put its code in your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17487687/edit) then and/or share a link to it, please.

Comment: Unfortunately today I don't have an access to this code. I can put part of the code in monday if won't find solution. T will try to explain what I have and what's a problem. So, on the screenshots you can see menu on the left. This menu contains references to page content. Each section is opening in div right from menu (like on the second screen), not in new window! Menu always displays correctly, problem is with page content. I have to change window size (resize/minimize/maximize) to see content (only under IE 10). I used something like:top.window.resizeTo(x,y) but is not good solution for me

Comment: I saw that resize of window is necessary only under IE 10, not older versions.